# Php как нормально отсортировать строку

Tags: php

Постараюсь вкратце обьяснить в чем проблема.

У нас есть определенная строка, пример:

> "asdasdasdasd asdasdas dasdasdasd &state=key&asdasd asdad asdasdasd"

Как мне из нее достать key?

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://example.com/';

    $headers = get_headers($url);
    print($headers[23]);
?>
```

В данном коде я получаю заголовок под номером 27, дальше мне нужно из него достать `&state = key` - мне нужен key. Так как я новичок в php (Это не C++,java или python), то мне довольно сложно понять как правильно это сделать, ведь он не может посчитать строку - массивом из букв.

Comment: Можно использовать регулярное выражение, покажи полную строку

Comment: @Yamich //example.com/?check=index&token=ffff535&state=key&id=6546  Из этой строки нам надо получить key

Answer (score 0):

не понятен вопрос. Рискну предположить по коду, что вам может помочь вот это: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php

Upd
Есть вариант попроще:

```
$a = $_GET['paramName'];
```

есть вариант [посложнее](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11480917/9179591)

Comment: У нас есть определенная строка. Пример:"asdasdasdasd asdasdas dasdasdasd &state=key&asdasd asdad asdasdasd" Как мне из нее достать key?

Comment: @AlexAmper поправил свой коммент

Answer (score 0):

```
$re = '/&state=([0-9a-zA-Z]*)&id/m';
$str = '//example.com/?check=index&token=ffff535&state=key&id=6546';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: достаточно просто `/&state=(.*?)&/`,  не усложняйте

Comment: @teran логично)

Answer (score 0):

Если таки пример строки такой как в комментариях, а не вопросе то используйте [`parse_str()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-str.php)

```
$str = "//example.com/?check=index&token=ffff535&state=key&id=6546";
parse_str($str, $data);

echo $data['state'];
```